# Как переслать фотографию Python (pyTelegrambotApi)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Как можно при помощи библиотеки PyTelegramBotApi переслать фотографию, которая была загружена в бота

Comment: Смотрели в документацию и примеры в PyTelegramBotApi? Попробуйте в декораторе обработчика указывать `content_type` с `photo`, так поймаете фотки, а далее делайте с ними что нужно

Comment: или сразу `forward` на нужный `id`

Comment: Хорошо, попробую как вы сказали, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def inline_keyboard(message):
    bot.copy_message(chat_id, from_chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id)
```

Работает так :
Если присылается фото, отправляет аналогичное сообщение в чат chat_id.(Ссылки на сообщение, которое было переслано не будет)

Comment: Пожалуйста, примите во внимание, в разделе справки: [Почему и как удаляются некоторые ответы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), кроме всего прочего, сказано:  _являются всего лишь ссылкой на другой сайт_.
Это сообщение, пожалуйста, или поправте, или удалите.